# The number of non-isomorphic ring structures that can be defined on $(Zp;+)$ where p is a prime number.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

Can someone help me with finding all non-isomoprhic structures  (or their number)?

So far i've found 2 non-ismomorphic :

1) $(Zp;+;*)$ with the classic product

2)
$(Zp;+;*) $ where $a*b = 0$ $\forall $ $ a$ ,$b$ in $Zp$

Can  someone help me find out the unit rings of Zn and help me prove that all of them are isomorphic?

Comment: I assume $p$ is a prime number. Assume there is a unit. Then the cyclic additive group spanned by this unit must be all of $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$, and then you can see that the ring is isomorphic with the classical ring of integers mod $p$. So the question is reduced to non unitary rings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For prime $p$ : 
As I noted in the comments, if the ring $R$ has a unit, then it must be isomorphic $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$. Indeed, if it has a unit $1$, then $\langle 1 \rangle$ is a non zero subgroup of a group of prime order: it is equal to the whole ring $R$.

Thus $\Bbb{Z}\to R, k\to k\cdot 1$ is surjective, and by the first isomorphism theorem, $R\simeq \Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$.

So when a ring is unital it is your ring 1).

Let's prove that if it is not your ring number 2), then it is unital, and then we'll be done.

So if it is not your ring 2), there are $a,b$ such that $ab\neq 0$.

Thus $\{ac, c\in R\}$ is a (additive) subgroup of $R$, that contains $0$ and $ab\neq 0$: thus by Lagrange's theorem (since $p$ is prime) it must be $R$. Thus $c\to ac$ is bijective. Let $d$ be such that $ad = a$. We'll prove that $d$ is a unit.

Since $c\to ac$ is bijective, it follows that for $c\neq 0$, $ac\neq 0$. Therefore for all $c$, $e\to ec$ is bijective (similar argument as earlier). For $c\in R$ we let $k_c$ be such that $k_c a = c$.

But then, $cd = k_c a d = k_c a = c$. Thus $d$ is a right unit.

By the same argument we can prove that there exists a left unit. But then the left and right unit in any monoid coincide, so it must be $d$: $d$ is a unit.

Therefore we are in case 1).

If we are not in case 2), we are in case 1). Therefore, we are either in case 1) or in case 2).

Notice that I've used that $p$ is prime multiple times, and so obviously this argument does not work for rings with additive group $\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$, $n$ not prime.